# Access function from custom directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my HTML. `genericsearch` is a directive:

```
<genericsearch  search-text="organisationSearchEvent"></genericsearch>
```

I was trying to call `organisationSearchEvent` but it was not getting called. How can I solve this?

**My directive**:

```
.directive('genericsearch', [function () {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
      objectType : '=',
      searchText: '=',

  },
  link:function(scope,elem,attrs) {    
      scope.myParam = 'tei_org';
  },
  controller: [
      '$scope',
      '$element',
      '$rootScope',
      'SearchOrg',
      'MapOrgs',
      '$routeParams',
      'DelOrgs',
      'GetTemplateGroups',
      'FetchOrgs',
      function($scope,$element,$rootScope,SearchOrg,MapOrgs,$routeParams,DelOrgs,GetTemplateGroups,FetchOrgs){
     $scope.organisationSearchEvent=  function(organisationSearchEvent,filter) {
              console.log('orglist'+JSON.stringify($scope.myParam));
              console.warn('text'+JSON.stringify($scope.text));
              SearchOrg().fetch({'filter':filter, 'searchType':'tei_org'}).$promise.then(

                function(value){
                    $scope.orgList = value.data;  
                },
                function(err){

              });
          });

          $scope.getOrgs = function(data, event) {
              if(event.keyCode != 13){
                  //$scope.Participants(data);
                  $scope.organisationSearchEvent(data);
              }
          }

          // console.log('orglist'+JSON.stringify($scope.orgList));
      }
],
templateUrl : TAPPLENT_CONFIG.HTML_ENDPOINT[0]+'home/search.html'
}}])
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, and the code doesn't help. In your code, you use ``organisationSearchEvent`` as a function in ``$scope.getOrgs``, and as a scope variable in your ``$watch``. Could you edit your code by removing all unnecessary code, and try to explain again what you want to achieve?

Comment: thnks for the reply i had done editing how should i can make this work?

Comment: So now, $scope.organisationSearchEvent is a function. From where do you want to call it? From the function ``$scope.getOrgs``, it should work, but you will get an error because ``filter``  is not defined.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to pass a function into the directive, or get a function from the directive into something else?

Comment: i was trying to make a directive to search and select the multiple items.

Comment: Please show also your template, I think it might help us

Comment: i am sorry i didnt get you. i was thinking to do like facebook search option but there we can search and select for one person but here we have to do multiple.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/BwDmM/300/ like wise i am trying to do custom directive